# Getting a value from dropdown buttons to use later

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, influxdb

I'm making a Django app that has 3 dropdown buttons Select host, select Filepath and Select Alert. I need to get back the selected values to use them later when running a InfluxDB script.
I'm new to Django and I'm having a lot of problems with this.
This is my index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Run Script</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Run Script</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="host_select">Select Host:</label>
            <select id="host_select" name="host_select" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              {% for x in hosts %}
              <option value="{{ x.host }}">{{ x.host }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="filepath_select">Select Filepath:</label>
            <select
              id="filepath_select"
              name="filepath_select"
              class="form-control"
            >
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              {% for x in filepaths %}
              <option value="{{ x.filepath }}">{{ x.filepath }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="alert_select">Select Alert:</label>
            <select id="alert_select" name="alert_select" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              {% for x in alerts %}
              <option value="{{ x.alert_name }}">{{ x.alert_name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />
      <button type="button" id="run_button" class="btn btn-primary">Run</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Hosts,Filepath,Alerts


def index(request):
    hosts=Hosts.objects.all().values()
    filepaths=Filepath.objects.all().values()
    alert=Alerts.objects.all().values()
    template=loader.get_template('index.html')
    context={
        'hosts':hosts,
        'filepaths':filepaths,
        'alerts':alert
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm quite stuck on this and I can't figure it out.

I tried everything I found online but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get back the selected values (host, filepath and alert) to use them in a python InfluxDB script later. The idea is that the customer can himself select that and click run which would run an InfluxDB python script that queries selected host and selected filepath on that host.

Comment: Please use a Django from to generate these. It will also make cleaning and validating data a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

what you need, is to get an idea of the "django model form".
Maybe this helps:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

You can then change values inside a model instance from your template and "store" data inside...
Modeldata could be saved from a template via POST, what you are normaly defining in the views.py...

If you could get us more details what you are trying to do, maybe we could help better..

Best regards,
David